# How to scrape aria-label text in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want scrape players name list from website, but names are on labels. I don't know how to scrape text on labels.
Here is the link
https://athletics.baruch.cuny.edu/sports/mens-swimming-and-diving/roster
For example, from html we have
How to scrape text from labels?

```
<div class="sidearm-roster-player-image column">                                                                    
  <a data-bind="click: function() { return true; }, clickBubble: false" href="/sports/mens-swimming-and-diving/roster/gregory-becker/3555" aria-label="Gregory Becker - View Full Bio" title="View Full Bio">
    <img class="lazyload" data-src="/images/2018/10/19/GREGORY_BECKER.jpg?width=80" alt="GREGORY BECKER">
  </a>                                                              
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.get()` method in BeautifulSoup. First select your element in `elem` or any other variable using any selector or `find/find_all`. Then try:

```
print(elem.get('aria-label'))
```

Comment: I still don't understand. I only learned list = list(soup.find_all('span', class_= ). How to select element? And in this case what is right element? The arra-label?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that will help you to extract name from the a tag

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("<path-to-html-file>") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser') #parse the html
    
tags = soup.find_all('a') # get all the a tag
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('aria-label')) #get the required text
```